# Unable to compile jitsi android source code in android studio

Tags: android, react-native, jitsi

When i am import the jitsi-meet android source code in android studio. then there is compiler error.

Failed to resolve: Could not resolve project :react-native-immersive. Required by: project :app > project :sdk Open File

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all dependencies with `npm install` first. That module is downloaded as part of that process.

In addition, you will need Android Studio 3.0 Preview.

Comment: Can describe how to install npm and where

Comment: npm is the Nodejs package manager. Have a look at nodejs.org.